# post and get conflict (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, github, webhooks

I'm currently experiencing an interessting Problem. I made my own way of auto deploying Websites from GitHub, but I ran into one issue. GitHub sends the payload over the webhook obviously as a POST Request. I have an `.htaccess` which encodes the url for me. So that it gets transformed to a GET Request, doesn't it? This is the line in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule v1/(.*)$ index.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

And I need the variables from there... I continue in PHP by making an array out of the GET Parameters with:

```
$url = explode("/", $_GET['request']);
```

In the processing I also make some GET requests to GitHubs API.

Now onto the the think that I don't understand. If I run the Webhook, my files don't get uploaded. If I open the site myself, everything gets updated as it should.

Maybe someone has an Idea of the cause and how to fix it?

Comment: _"So that it gets transformed to a GET Request, doesn't it? "_ - no, that would only happen if it was an _external_ redirect, which would make the client send a new request altogether. As long as it is an internal redirect only, there is no reason for the request method to change.

Comment: Why does this then make the code cancel? `if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== "GET") return;` @CBroe

Answer (score 0):

I just solved my own problem. After waiting for good ~5 Minutes, I executed the Webhook again and the changes were on the Webspace. So probably the GitHub API is at the moment just *slow*, or it doesn't updates that often.